# How can I design smart contracts for p2p vehicle trading?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, nft

The idea is to have two contracts:

- OrderManager Contract
- NFTMinting Contract

OrderManager will manage the funds transfer for the vehicle; buyer will deposit the funds, the seller will withdraw them; they can both cancel the order in which case the funds will be returned deposit

NFTMinting Contract will be used to mint the NFT of the vehicle to the address of teh buyer upon successufl transaction of funds.

What shall be a good design to design these contracts esp the NFTMinting contract for a vehicle?

Since each vehicle (say a car) is unique or can be one of thousands of the available car models in the world; as per the provisions of the ERC721 Contract i would have to create contracts for all of them?

Either that or i have the following other options:

- Mint a new NFT for each new vehicle regardless of its make/model
- Make an ERC1155 contract but then i would have to assign IDs to every available car model (see [ERC1155 OpenZepplin Docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155))

Besides these what other options do I have for an elegant solution to this problem?